# How can I convert from contour vector to MAT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour, mat

This is the code I have to find the contour of an image:

```
contour, heir= cv2.findContours(hmg,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I want to find the area of a contour with

```
cv2.contourArea(contour)
```

but that needs a MAT datatype, and not the contour vector type

How can I convert contour so I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contour` object is in fact a list of all contours found in the image, each of which are in the correct format. A name like `contours` might be more appropriate, but that's non-essential.

Your post assumes a singular contour; this is rarely the case due to filtering noise, but you could single the contour out by sorting by descending area:

```
contours, heir= cv2.findContours(hmg,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
print(cv2.contourArea(contours[0]))
```